# How to bypass deep xml, no nested loops?

Tags: go

I have deep nested xml object:

```
type Obj struct{
     Scripts  []*Script `xml:"scripts"`
}

type Script struct{
    ID string `xml:"id"`
    Tables []*Table `xml:"tables"`
}

type Table struct{
     Elements []*Element `xml:"elements"`
     Tables   []*Table   `xml:"tables"`
}

type Element struct{
     Key string `xml:"key"`
     Val string `xml:"val"`
}
```

I need to get a list of Element from Object with the right keys.How can this be done without a nested loop:

```
for _, s:= range obj{
     if s.ID == "requireID"{
          for _, table:= range s.Tables{
                    for _, t:= range table.Tables{
                         for _, el:= range t.Elements{
                              if el.Key == "requireKey"{
                                   elements = elements.append(elements, el)
                              }    
                         }
                    }
                }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use a nested loop?

Comment: @mrasoolmirzaei The task is to avoid nesting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete working solution using stack. It is more complex than using nested loops:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Obj struct {
    Scripts []*Script `xml:"scripts>script"`
}

type Script struct {
    ID     string   `xml:"id"`
    Tables []*Table `xml:"tables>table"`
}

type Table struct {
    Elements []*Element `xml:"elements>element"`
    Tables   []*Table   `xml:"tables>table"`
}

type Element struct {
    Key string `xml:"key"`
    Val string `xml:"val"`
}

func main() {
    // Example XML data
    xmlData := `
    <obj>
        <scripts>
            <script>
                <id>requireID</id>
                <tables>
                    <table>
                        <elements>
                            <element>
                                <key>requireKey</key>
                                <val>value1</val>
                            </element>
                        </elements>
                        <tables>
                            <table>
                                <elements>
                                    <element>
                                        <key>requireKey</key>
                                        <val>value2</val>
                                    </element>
                                </elements>
                            </table>
                        </tables>
                    </table>
                </tables>
            </script>
        </scripts>
    </obj>
    `

    var obj Obj
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    // Call the iterative function to find elements with specific ID and Key
    elements := findElements("requireID", "requireKey", &obj)
    for _, el := range elements {
        fmt.Println("Element Key:", el.Key, "Value:", el.Val)
    }
}

// Helper function to convert slice to []interface{} slice
func toInterfaceSlice(slice interface{}) []interface{} {
    s := make([]interface{}, 0)
    switch slice.(type) {
    case []*Script:
        for _, v := range slice.([]*Script) {
            s = append(s, v)
        }
    case []*Table:
        for _, v := range slice.([]*Table) {
            s = append(s, v)
        }
    case []*Element:
        for _, v := range slice.([]*Element) {
            s = append(s, v)
        }
    }
    return s
}

func findElements(requiredID, requiredKey string, rootObj interface{}) []*Element {
    var elements []*Element
    stack := []interface{}{rootObj}

    for len(stack) > 0 {
        // Pop the top element from the stack
        obj := stack[len(stack)-1]
        stack = stack[:len(stack)-1]

        switch v := obj.(type) {
        case *Obj:
            for _, script := range v.Scripts {
                if script.ID == requiredID {
                    stack = append(stack, script)
                }
            }
        case *Script:
            stack = append(stack, toInterfaceSlice(v.Tables)...)
        case *Table:
            for _, el := range v.Elements {
                if el.Key == requiredKey {
                    elements = append(elements, el)
                }
            }
            stack = append(stack, toInterfaceSlice(v.Tables)...)
        }
    }

    return elements
}
```